# R include commas and show max dp for numbers

Tags: r

is there any way for me to include commas for large numbers example show 1000000 as 1,000,000 and at the same time display the max number of decimals for each. I've looked through some of the questions asked, doesnt seem to have an option to do both. I tried

`format(1000000, big.mark = ",")`

which tends to round off the numbers. and if i include the nsmall option, it changes the dp for all the values. So the ideal output i want for a column of numbers is to show the max decimals if they have any and not show any if they dont. So it looks something like this:

```
1000000 -> 1,000,000
10043.9658 - > 10,043.9658
5005.3 -> 5,000.3
```

As you can see above, it doesnt show decimal if it doesnt have any and shows the max decimals if it has any to begin with.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `sapply()` with `format()` ensuring the `digits` argument is set to a suitable minimum width and the `scientific` notation argument is set to `FALSE`.

```
sapply(c(1000000, 10043.9658, 5005.3), format, big.mark = ",", digits = 12, scientific = FALSE)

[1] "1,000,000"   "10,043.9658" "5,005.3"
```

Comment: I don't seem to get `"1,000,000"`, but rather `"1e+06"` (Win7)

Comment: To be prudent, adding `scientific = F` will prevent `"1e+06"`. Resulting `sapply(c(1000000, 10043.9658, 5005.3), format, big.mark = ",", digits=12, scientific = F)`